# Trivial vertex cover in regular graph is 2-approximation Proof

Tags: graphs, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-cover, vertex-cover

I need to show that in any regular graph, taking all nodes gives a 2-approximation vertex cover.

My attempt: I am proving that every $k$-regular graph can be reduced to a 2-regular fully connected graph (ring). And then the ring case is trivial.

However, I am unable to show that in the actual graph, there was no smaller vertex cover than the one of size $|V|/2$. I tried by induction, but I am unsure if I should fix the number of nodes or the factor of regularness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $k$-regular graph with $n$ nodes has $nk/2$ edges. Since all vertices have degree $k$, no vertex cover can contain less than $\frac{nk/2}{k} = n/2$ vertices.